# ZF2 - Get path of current view template in custom view helper

Tags: php, zend-framework2

In Zend Framework 2, I am trying to get the path of the current view template in a custom view helper.

If I have a view helper called "testThis" and I am rendering a template located at view/inside/bar/baz.phtml then I want to be able to get this path from within the "testThis" __invoke method.

This should always get the calling view though - for example if inside this baz.phtml file I use the partial helper to load another template called boo.phtml, then if I called "testThis" from within this boo.phtml template I would get that path instead of the baz.phtml.

Is this possible and if so, how to do it?

Edit: If I add a function to Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer that returns the private variable $__template then I get exactly what I need but it would be nice to not have to modify the framework - is there a way to get it without adding this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no.
First of all, you have already figured out that the file name is private in Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer. Second, it well could be something completely different, for instance ZfcTwig\View\Resolver\TwigResolver, which does not have such a property.

Comment: Roger. It would be nice if it would just return null if there is no property because all the times when I would like to use it I have the property set (or if it is null, then thats also fine for my usage). I just added a getTemplate() method to my copy of Zend so hopefully I dont forget about that next time I update framework

Comment: You should rather write your own renderer.